# Sfinae and template specialization

Tags: c++11, templates

I want to provide a function in my library:

```
namespace Foo {
template<typename G>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<G>::value, std::vector<uint8_t>>::type toBytes(const G &g) {
//something here
}
}
```

However I want to provide basic implementation only for basic types. If an user wants to add a specialization I thought it was enough to write in the user code:

```
namespace Foo {
template<>
std::vector<uint8_t> toBytes<struct A>(const struct A &g) {
//something here
}
}
```

However it doesn't compile, Gcc provides this error:

> std::vector Foo::toBytes(const A&)’ does not match any
>   template declaration

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Common wisdom is to overload, not specialize in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the C++20 feature `Concept`.`Concept`s naturally also support template specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {
    template<typename T, typename U >
    concept SameHelper = std::is_same_v<T, U>;
}

template<typename T, typename U >
concept same_as = detail::SameHelper<T, U> && detail::SameHelper<U, T>;

template<typename T>
concept fundamental = same_as<T, bool> || same_as<T, char>;

template<typename T>
void toBytes(T) {std::cout << "I am not fundamental" << std::endl;}  

template<fundamental T>
void toBytes(T){std::cout << "I am fundamental" << std::endl;}


int main() {
    toBytes(true);
    toBytes('c');
    toBytes(1);
}
```

[You can run the code online](https://godbolt.org/z/AEe2KP) to see the following output:

```
I am fundamental
I am fundamental
I am not fundamental
```

Comment: I can only use c++11

Comment: @greywolf82 Too bad. Maybe next time you make it clear that you are limited to c++11.

Comment: it's the reason why the question is tagged c++11

Comment: @greywolf82 Ok, then I suggest deleting the tag c++